# Declaring a static pointer to an inner class object in a template

Tags: templates, c++11, inner-classes, static-members

I'm trying to create a simple template binary search tree for practice, and I currently have something like the following in a header file:

```
template <class T_Satellite, class T_Key>
class bst {
    struct bst_node;
    static const bst_node* nullnode;
}
```

My problem currently stems from trying to define `nullnode` in the cpp file. I've tried:

```
template <class T_Satellite, class T_Key>
const bst<T_Satellite, T_Key>::bst_node * bst::nullnode = bst_node(nullptr, nullptr);
```

and

```
template <class T_Satellite, class T_Key>
const bst<T_Satellite, T_Key>::bst_node * bst::nullnode(nullptr, nullptr);
```

But neither seem to work at all. I have a definition for `bst_node` in my cpp file as well. The compiler spits out that

```
'std::bst<T_Satellite,T_Key>::nullnode' : static data member cannot be initialized via derived class'
```

in the first example as well as

```
'std::bst<T_Satellite,T_Key>::bst_node' : dependent name is not a type.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `typename` keyword:

```
template <class T_Satellite, class T_Key>
const typename bst<T_Satellite, T_Key>::bst_node * bst::nullnode = bst_node(nullptr, nullptr);
```

The error message referencing "dependent name" is the clue. `typename` must be used for all dependent names that reference a type. A name is ["dependent"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) if it involves an unbound template parameter.

Additionally, you'll almost certainly need to move this into your header file since the name will need to be instantiated with the actual used template parameters unless you're doing explicit instantiation.

Comment: I was under the impression that modern compilers could handle template definitions in a separate file...how is this any different with a static const variable?

Answer (score 0):

Dependent names are those that depend on a template parameter. Dependent names are not treated as types to avoid [ambiguity](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) - the compiler doesn't have a way of knowing if the name refers to a member or a type. This is where you need to use the `typename` keyword.

Refer to the type `bst_node` as

```
template <class T_Satellite, class T_Key>
const typename bst<T_Satellite, T_Key>::bst_node
```